# error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ in assignment

Tags: c++, string, char

I have an executable called as a shell script:

```
./lineGraph argv[1] argv[2] ... argv[9]
```

It creates an instance of the class lineGraph (code simplified tremendously here):

```
class lineGraph
{
  string z[3];

  lineGraph(string lumi, string label, char *typeArg, string volume, string axisStyle, string theLine, string z1, string z2, string z3)
  {
    this->z[0]=z1;
    this->z[1]=z2;
    this->z[2]=z3;
  }
}

public int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  lineGraph *graphData = new lineGraph(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], argv[6], argv[7], argv[8], argv[9]);
};
```

And I get:

```
lineGraph.cc:251: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ in assignment
lineGraph.cc:252: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ in assignment
lineGraph.cc:253: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char’ in assignment
```

Here:

```
this->z[0]=z1;
this->z[1]=z2;
this->z[2]=z3;
```

I'm curious about a solution, and also an explanation of why it's giving me an error (I'm setting an element of a string[] to a string, which I'd think would be permissible).  There's probably something fundamental I'm missing, as my C++ is rusty.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:  issue resolved.  Was a sneaky variable declaration overwriting the z[] declaration.

Comment: Please post real code.  `argv` is not declared in `main` above.

Comment: Well, for a start, `argv` doesn't exist. That's how we know this testcase is nonsense. Show us your _real_ code; the code that you've been debugging; the code that you've been attempting to compile.. the code that **actually** contains the fault.

Comment: Just a guess but it looks like `z` in your real code is probably declared as a string instead of an array of strings. Post your real code and you'll get a real solution.

Comment: `(code simplified tremendously here)` Well done for doing this, but you really should have done it _before_ doing your final debugging, and you definitely should have tested it before posting it here! It makes the problem go away (and introduces a new one).

Comment: Why you no `lineGraph graphData(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], argv[6], argv[7], argv[8], argv[9]);`?

Answer (score 5):

There are several errors in the code:

1. Missing `;` after the class declaration.
2. `argv` is not declared, you should write `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.
3. Constructor of the class is private (should be public).

But after correcting these errors the code compiles just fine. There is no any `cannot convert std::string to char` error.

Probably you are trying to compile something different, not the code you show us.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce the errors you get is to change `z` to a single `string` instead of an array of strings. The example below produces the same results you are gettings

```
class lineGraph
{
    string z;

public:
    lineGraph(string lumi, string label, char * /*typeArg*/, string volume, string axisStyle, string theLine, string z1, string z2, string z3)
    {
        this->z[0]=z1;
        this->z[1]=z2;
        this->z[2]=z3;
    }
};
```

This produces the following results on VS2010. The error codes may vary slightly depending on the toolchain you are using.

> main.cpp(587): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'
>   1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   1>main.cpp(588): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'
>   1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   1>main.cpp(589): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'
>   1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Double check your actual code and make sure `z` is decalred as an array like so

```
class lineGraph
{
    string z[3];

    // ...more REAL code...
};
```

Comment: This fixed the issue:  I had a sneaky "string z" hiding somewhere, overwriting the "string z[]".